# Selenium - Discerning Between Identical <articles>, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, article, tagname

I'm trying to have my program sit on a webpage and wait for specific tagName within an article to appear. Problem is, I need Selenium to check the article contains two tagNames before clicking it, that's where I'm stumped. The way I have my code setup right now, it doesn't click anywhere. It just sits on the page, I suspect because there's more than one article with the same main tagName that I'm trying to find. Here's the HTML:

```
<article>
   <div class ="inner-article">
      <a href ="/shop/shirts/iycbmgtqw/x9vdawcjg" style="height:150px;">
         <img alt="Xrtqh7ar444" height="150" src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/120885/vi/xrTQH7Ar444.jpg" width="150">
      </a>
      <h1>
        <a href="/shop/shirts/iycbmgtqw/x9vdawcjg" class="name-link">EXAMPLE_CODE</a>
      </h1>
      <p>
        <a href="/shop/shirts/iycbmgtqw/x9vdawcjg" class="name-link">EXAMPLE_COLOUR</a>
      </p>
   </div>
</article>
```

All other items on this page have an identical class, and some have identical tagNames. I want to search for when there's a specific combination of two tagNames in an article. I realize xPath is an option, but I would like to code it before knowing an xPath, where the name of the item is the only available information.

And here's the code I'm working with at the moment:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));


IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.TagName(textBox12.Text));
test.Click();
```

where textBox12.Text is "EXAMPLE_CODE". Am I correct in assuming that WebDriver doesn't click anything because there is more than one element with the tagName "EXAMPLE_CODE", and is there a possible way to make it first look for "EXAMPLE_CODE" and then check the secondary: "EXAMPLE_COLOUR"?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `By.TagName` incorrectly. Tag refers to the type of element you are trying to find. In this case for the link it is 'a'. Or in case of a div it is 'div'. Te correct way of finding with tagname for a link would be -  `By.TagName("a")`.

You need to match text and you will need to use xpath. Assuming that the code is unique you should try.

XPath to get the code href -- `//div[class='inner-article']/h1/a[.=EXAMPLE_CODE]`

XPath to get the color href -- `//div[class='inner-article']/h1/a[.=EXAMPLE_CODE]/following-sibling::a`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes sense, I'll try using xPath. What I'm still confused about is how to set up the code to use both xpaths to determine which webelement to select?

Comment: @ClarkMcMaster Can you be more specific with what is tripping you up?

Comment: IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[class='inner-article']/h1/a[.=EXAMPLE_CODE]"));
            test.Click();            As you can see, I use xpath to search for EXAMPLE_CODE, and then click it. What I don't know how to do is search for all articles with EXAMPLE_CODE, and then click the one with the color href. I don't know how to search for an element that fills both criteria. Sorry, I know I'm not explaining it well!